# PHP - Checking if a timedate has past

Tags: php, if-statement, time

```
$from = time();
$to = strtotime($row['clock']);
if($to<$from){
    echo("Time has past.");
}
```

I am just trying to check if the time has past with a simple IF statement.

Currently the if statement is always true, no matter the datetime.

$row['clock'] = 2013-10-31 00:04:00

Comment: Minor comment - the correct grammar would be to write "Time has passed." rather than 'past'.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine here. Make sure `$row['clock']` contains what you think it does.

```
$from = time();
$to = strtotime('2013-11-01 00:00:00');
if($to<$from){
    echo("Time has past.");
}
```

echos nothing on my machine, while:

```
$from = time();
$to = strtotime('2013-10-01 00:00:00');
if($to<$from){
    echo("Time has past.");
}
```

echos "Time has past.".

Barring that, check that your server's time is correctly set.

Comment: Time on server is fine etc. I am using it to check that the countdown timer has finished. It counts down fine, but this if statement remains true no matter what.

Comment: The 2 times are 1383182400
1383185737

Comment: Problem turned out to be PHP time. Was +1 hour. Changed timezone in php.ini